# How to retrieve the scrollbar position of the webbrowser control in .NET

Tags: c#

I tried using `webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollTop` and `webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollLeft`, but they don't work. They always return 0 and I can't access `webBrowser1.Document.documentElement.ScrollTop` and `.ScrollLeft`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, I solved it:

```
Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = wb.Document
Dim scrollTop As Integer = htmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")(0).ScrollTop
```

Comment: I have searched the vast web high and low and viewed myriad solutions which have not worked, but this, finally this, gave me what I wanted.  Thank you, Marc.

Comment: This does not work!!!, Method name expected?? plz tell me what i'm missing i to have searched the web high and low for 3 days :'(

Comment: This answer is written in VB.

Comment: Also, there is System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser and System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser. Finding code online can be very confusing if you are working with the other WebBrowser class.

Comment: I put the C# equivalent of Marc's VB code in an answer below. It works :)

Answer (score 5):

To actually scroll, we found that the [`ScrollIntoView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.scrollintoview.aspx) method worked nicely. For example, to scroll to the top-left of the page.

```
 this.webBrowser.Document.Body.FirstChild.ScrollIntoView(true);
```

However, we were not successful in actually getting the scroll position (that said, we didn't spend long trying). If you are in control of the HTML content, you might consider using some javascript to copy the scroll position into a hidden element and then read that value out using the DOM.

[`ScrollTop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.scrolltop.aspx) and [`ScrollLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.scrollleft.aspx) merely allow an offset to be provided between the boundary of an element and its content. There appears to be no way to manipulate the scroll by those values. Instead, you have to use [`ScrollIntoView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.scrollintoview.aspx).

Comment: I'm not in control of the HTML content so that won't work for me. I do know about the ScrollIntoView and ScrollTo functions, but instead of scrolling i want to access the scrollbar in the webbrowser component to read out the values. I could of course insert some javascript in the page myself and let it read out the values, but that's an option i rather not use.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested, here's the C# code equivalent to Marc's answer:

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = webBrowser.Document;
if (htmlDoc != null)
{
    int scrollTop = htmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].ScrollTop;
    int scrollLeft = htmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].ScrollLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to query the scroll position using this

```
        if (this.webBrowser.Document != null)
        {
            int scrollPosition = this webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollTop;                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `documentElement`

```
IHTMLElement2 page = 
(wb.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument3).documentElement as IHTMLElement2;
int pos = page.scrollTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is VB. For C# WPF WebBrowser, I had to write the following. No idea if I really need all those casts or not. If one can get rid of any of those casts, that would be terrific.

```
using mshtml;
int? GetScrollTop(System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser browser)
{
  object doc = browser.Document;
  HTMLDocument castDoc = doc as HTMLDocument;
  IHTMLElementCollection elements = castDoc?.getElementsByTagName("HTML");
  IEnumerator enumerator = elements?.GetEnumerator();
  enumerator?.MoveNext();
  var first = enumerator?.Current;
  IHTMLElement2 castFirst = first as IHTMLElement2;
  int? top = castFirst?.scrollTop;
  return top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found kurt's answer almost worked but had to change the array reference as follows:

```
var document = (HTMLDocument)Browser.Document;
var scrollTop = (int)document.getElementsByTagName("HTML").item(0).ScrollTop;
```