# How can i get the current vertical position of the scroll bar in a web browser?

Tags: c#, .net

I can set the scroll position:

```
webCompareSQL.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0,0);
```

But how can i get it?

Answer (score 1):

The following link is similar to your question.

[How to retrieve the scrollbar position of the webbrowser control in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277691/how-to-retrieve-the-scrollbar-position-of-the-webbrowser-control-in-net)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank iv see it, i have a unanswered comment on that question, its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on that page Gaz mentioned.

[Here is the MSDN documentation on it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

why doesn't ...

```
 int top = webCompareSQL.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].ScrollTop;
```

work?

Comment: GetElementsTagName is underlined in red

Comment: @Pomster Do you mean GetElementsByTagName?